# Kill all database connections on heroku when max connections have been reached

Tags: postgresql, heroku, kill

My instance has a maximum number of connections of 16. As soon as I realized that I had **19** connections, I hurried to kill one, which turns out to open a standard connection with the same priority and limitations.

I have now reached the absolute maximum number of connection, which is **20**, and cannot even do a `pg:ps` or a `pg:killall`.

How can I kill all connections, or do anything to lower the number of connections now? The query which seems to be blocking is extremely long (seems like a `select *` from a table which has 410k entries).

```
$ heroku pg:info -a XYZ
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Basic
Status:      Available
Connections: 19
PG Version:  9.1.11
Created:     2013-03-12 15:11 UTC
Data Size:   7.16 GB
Tables:      103
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
$ heroku pg:ps -a XYZ
 procpid | source |   running_for   | waiting | (...)
$ heroku pg:kill 12593 -a XYZ
 pg_cancel_backend 
-------------------
 t
(1 row)

$ heroku pg:ps -a XYZ
psql: FATAL:  too many connections for role "abc"
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    Backtrace:   /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:442:in `version'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:447:in `nine_two?'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:451:in `pid_column'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:226:in `ps'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:37:in `start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku pg:ps -a XYZ
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.9.6 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.0.0
$ heroku pg:killall -a XYZ
psql: FATAL:  too many connections for role "abc"
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    Backtrace:   /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:442:in `version'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:447:in `nine_two?'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:451:in `pid_column'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:272:in `killall'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
                 /home/chris/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:37:in `start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku pg:killall -a XYZ
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.9.6 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.0.0
$ heroku pg:info -a XYZ
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Basic
Status:      Available
Connections: 20
PG Version:  9.1.11
Created:     2013-03-12 15:11 UTC
Data Size:   8.24 GB
Tables:      103
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

Comment: Im running on the same problem 2 hrs ago. And i either have acces to the heroku pg:ps, you have found anything yet?

Comment: @JorgeNajeraT, I did not find a solution which I know works. Thirty minutes after posting the question, all the connections seemed to have been killed although the `killall` statement did not go through. All I did was connect through a command line, connected to my database (with `\connect db_name;`) and then realized that all the connections had been dropped. Maybe does forcing a pg shell to open close all other connections if none are available, I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the following toolbelt add-on which worked perfectly.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras#usage

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to promote another DB and assign the original again

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-basic 
#Attached as NEW_DATABASE_URL

heroku pg:promote NEW_DATABASE_URL

heroku pg:promote ORIGINAL_DATABASE_URL
```

Then verify your db connections